# Fabric.js - Blur filter makes dark border / glow on clipped images

Tags: fabricjs

When I use blur filter on fabric.Image object with transparent PNG it looks ok. But when I use clipPath on fabric.Image object, then make transparent PNG with toDataURL() or cloneAsImage() and then blur it, it makes strange dark glow. Any idea how to get rid of it?

```
class Board {
  constructor(id) {
    this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas(id)
    this.filter = new fabric.Image.filters.Blur({
      blur: 0.5
    })
  }
  addImage(url) {
    fabric.Image.fromURL(url, (img) => {
      this.image = img
      this.canvas.setWidth(img.width)
      this.canvas.setHeight(img.height)
      this.canvas.add(img)
    })
  }
  addBlur() { // OK
    this.blurImage(this.image)
  }
  addClipAndBlur() { // Not OK
    const circle = new fabric.Circle({
      radius: 100,
      fill: 'red',
      left: 150,
      top: 150,
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',
      absolutePositioned: true
    })
    this.image.clipPath = circle
    this.canvas.remove(this.image)
    this.image.cloneAsImage((image) => {
      this.canvas.add(image)
      this.blurImage(image)
    })
  }
  blurImage(image) {
    image.filters.push(this.filter)
    image.applyFilters()
    this.canvas.renderAll()
  }
}
```

See https://codepen.io/ultradeq/pen/RwbXZKm?editors=0010
board1 = transparent PNG, board2 = clipped image

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround way for this issue. Overriding the `toCanvasElement` method (http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.js.html#line15767) and fill the canvas will `ffffff01` instead of keeping it completely transparent.

It solves the problem for me.